# How to create a custom Site Search in Chrome that uses Google's I'm Feeling Lucky

Tags: google-chrome, search

I like to be able type `ltf` and then a `space` and then my query such as `kms_alias` which should perform an "I'm feeling lucky" search for `terraform kms_alias` and therefore bring me to https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/kms_alias .

I was using the following as the definition, and it stopped working (recently?):

```
{google:baseURL}search?ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&sourceid=navclient&gfns=1&q=terraform%20%s
```

Now, this just brings me to the regular search results page (not the top result).

I have tried the suggestions in [How to create a link that uses Google's "I'm Feeling Lucky"?](https://superuser.com/questions/56021/how-to-create-a-link-that-uses-googles-im-feeling-lucky) and [How can I search with Google's I'm Feeling Lucky feature directly from Chrome's omnibox?](https://superuser.com/questions/1143945/how-can-i-search-with-googles-im-feeling-lucky-feature-directly-from-chromes) .  They both result in a regular results page.